# HTTP Trigger Azure Function : OutOfMemoryException not logged in monitor

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I was just going through the Azure functions, and was trying to check behavior of Azure function when exception is occurred. I went through the documentation provided by Microsoft on Error handling and made a very simple HTTP Trigger. Here is the

**CODE**

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
{
 log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

 string name = req.Query["name"];

try
{
    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;
    switch (name)
        {
            case "OutOfMemoryException":               
                throw new System.OutOfMemoryException();
            case "NullReferenceException":
                throw new System.NullReferenceException();
            case "IndexOutOfRangeException":
                throw new System.IndexOutOfRangeException();
            case "InvalidOperationException":
                throw new System.InvalidOperationException();
            case "ArgumentNullException":
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException();
            default:
                break;
        }
}
catch(System.Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}

return name != null
    ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
    : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

**ISSUE**

I am unable to see the logs when a memory out of exception occured. Its not here and not in application insights as well, it gets logged into the console but that temp only. Inbetween the first two logs in the list, I fired an OutOfMemoryException, however there is no log of it.

**Is this a known issue in Azure ?**

[image: Monitor Scrrenshot]

[image]

Comment: Did you disable built in error handling.To disable built-in logging, delete the AzureWebJobsDashboard app setting

Comment: No I did not disable it.

Comment: @AnassKartit: Added screenshot of app settings cant see such settings called azurewebjobsdashboard

Comment: UPDATE: adding the #r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" on the top  and Anass Answer helped me resolve

Comment: Why down voted my question. @Moderator: What went wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

`OutOfMemoryException` is a special exception compared to others in your list. Function host will be shut down once this exception is thrown, and no log is sent to Application Insights as you have found.

IMO, the `OutOfMemoryException` is usually thrown and handled by function host itself as we may have no method to handle memory problem in our own code. If you are going to set your own memory limitation, my suggestion is not to throw the exception to function host, we could log the exception by ourselves.

```
catch(System.Exception ex)
{
    log.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
}
```

We could also track all logs in kudu, go to `https://<functionAppName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and navigate to `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\function\<FunctionName>` to check function-specific logs.

Answer (score 1):

according to this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/durable-diagnostics

You have to catch the exception and log it using the logger to see it in app insight:

```
 catch (FunctionFailedException ex)
    {
        log.Error("Some Exception occured ", ex);
    }
```

Comment: you don't need any addditional assembly since your logger is already reference.  ILogger log

Comment: In VS, its marked as the type or namespace "FunctionFailedException" could not be found

Comment: you have to use durable functions using DurableOrchestrationContext, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-create-first-csharp

Comment: Ok, I got you point. However here i am trying to fix for HttpTrigger, I understand that Durable orchestrator is Http only. but since microsoft gave two different options. So i am sticking to first one to explore more such issues

Comment: in that case, you have to catch Exception ex and log it using Log.Error, also your question was tagged using Durable Functions so the answer to that is what I provided earlier.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have removed the Tag. I was not aware of the same. Thanks for all the help. However catch via exception ex does not work for memory out of exception. I tried that.